# Why openjdk uses an unsafe construct?

Tags: generics, java, raw-types

Reading some of the code of openjdk7, I have found method Collections.reverse implemented as (I've removed some optimization for RandomAccess lists):

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    ListIterator fwd = list.listIterator();
    ListIterator rev = list.listIterator(size);
    for (int i = 0, mid = list.size() >> 1; i < mid; i++) {
        Object tmp = fwd.next();
        fwd.set(rev.previous());
        rev.set(tmp);
    }
}
```

Where both initializations of the ListIterators generate unchecked warnings (and no @SupressWarnings anotation is in the code).

For me the save and simple way to implement would be:

```
public static <E> void reverse2(List<E> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    ListIterator<E> fwd = list.listIterator();
    ListIterator<E> rev = list.listIterator(size);
    for (int i = 0, mid = list.size() >> 1; i < mid; i++) {
        E tmp = fwd.next();
        fwd.set(rev.previous());
        rev.set(tmp);
    }
}
```

which is completely safe.

My questions are:

- Why is openjdk using the unsafe code using raw-types?
- Why is the warning not suppressed?

Comment: I believe the point there is avoiding having to name the type variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trade-off. The JDK developers accept a warning on their side to reduce warnings for other developers. If you are compiling old code using a `List`, i.e. as raw type, you can pass it to `Collections.reverse()` without warnings as it is safe. But if `Collections.reverse()` had a type parameter like in `public static <E> void reverse(List<E> list)` you received a warning when trying to invoke it with the raw type `List`.

Comment: Thanks. This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I have found this answered on the Generics Faq:

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ302A

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, `reverse()` just takes a `List` of any parameter. It doesn't care at all, nor does it need the parameter to be related to some other type. Therefore, `void reverse(List<?> list)` is the simplest (and therefore best) signature.

Now, to write it properly in generics, inside the implementation of `reverse`, there is a need to use the type parameter of the list, because we need to take an element from the list, and put it back, and we need a type to express this temporary value.

The only way to do this in Java is to have a generic parameter declared for the whole method -- making it a generic method -- as your `reverse2` does: `<E> void reverse2(List<E> list)`

However, this changes the signature (which is visible to the outside). The `E` here is only used in one place in the parameters, and is basically unnecessary from a type point of view. The fact we need to use `E` internally is an implementation detail that outside code doesn't need to care about.

There is a way to do this that uses completely safe constructs AND preserves the signature `void reverse(List<?> list)`: using a *capture helper*. i.e. make a helper method that takes `List<?>`, and all it does is call the generic method (which can then be made private):

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list) {
    reverse2(list);
}
```

(If you don't understand why that is correct under generics, hint: it's due to capture.)

Even though that seems to have the best of both worlds (simpler signature + safe constructs), the downside is that it is, from a runtime point of view, a waste. We have a method taking one parameter which all it does is pass it directly to another method taking one parameter. It seems completely extraneous. After type erasure -- you would have one method taking `List` calling another method taking `List`. (If I showed you such a function, and you didn't know about generics, you would probably immediately think it was unnecessary.)

So in the interest of efficiency, they decided to sacrifice completely safe constructs in the internal code, in order to preserve the simpler signature and the efficiency of a single function call rather than two. The constructs they use are in the internal code anyway, so nobody but Java library developers should care about it; after type erasure, the code is exactly the same as the safe code, so there would be no difference in the binary. Whereas the signature and efficiency of the compiled code both affect the users of the library.